# Pass all file names as parameter to vbscript in loop

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have several text files in one folder. I want to call **ALL** these files like this

> ParseAllFiles.bat

```
cscript ParseFile.vbs File1.txt
cscript ParseFile.vbs Test.txt
cscript ParseFile.vbs Log.txt
...
...
...
cscript ParseFile.vbs Code.txt
```

How can I call like this by loop?
All *.txt files should be called like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.txt) do cscript ParseFile.vbs "%%~f"
```

Of course you could also modify the VBScript code to loop over all files in the current directory:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(".").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "txt" Then
    ...
  End If
Next
```